# Dynamic "enquiry" link based on data in table row

Tags: jquery, html-table, var

Using jQuery I want to add an "Enquiry" column to the end of any table with class "table". This column should contain an email link which includes a dynamic subject line based on the information presented in its row.

I've made some jQuery which gets some of the above done, namely it creates the new column and an email link, but I have no idea how to use a variable to manipulate the link to include that rows 'Module' and 'Date' fields.

**The Table**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Module</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Venue</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Jan 01</td>
            <td>Module 1 – Example</td>
            <td>£100 (+ VAT)</td>
            <td>Example location, Example City</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jan 01</td>
            <td>Module 2 – Example</td>
            <td>£100 (+ VAT)</td>
            <td>Example location, Example City</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My incomplete jQuery**

```
$('table.table').find('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('th').eq(3).after('<th>Enquire</th>');
    $(this).find('td').eq(3).after('<td><a class="mailenquiry" href="mailto:foo@foo.co.uk?subject=Enquiry about MODULE HERE on DATE HERE">Enquire</a></td>');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51x48vfc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:eq` selector with `text()` to find the text of a given `td` in the row and then append it to the HTML. Try this:

```
$('table.table tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    var date = $row.find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var module = $row.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    $row.find('th:last').after('<th>Enquire</th>');
    $row.find('td:last').after('<td><a class="mailenquiry" href="mailto:foo@foo.co.uk?subject=Enquiry about ' + module + ' on ' + date + '">Enquire</a></td>');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/51x48vfc/1/)

I also tidied the code a little by joining some selectors, caching the `tr` element and using `:last` which is more robust should you decide to add some more rows at a later date.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you for tidying my code, I appreciate that it provides more flexibility.

Comment: No problem, glad to help